# filter() array by another array some() not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

In the following method, I need to filter the first array based on whether the items id exists in the second array. For some reason this returns empty for me though.

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((airlines: AirlineModel[]) => {
    console.log(airlines, this.airlines);
    const updates = airlines.filter(airline => this.airlines.some(item => item.id === airline.id));
    console.log(updates);
});
```

`console.log(airlines, this.airlines);` results in:

```
(13) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: "1", code: "AAL", name: "American Airlines"}
1: {id: "6", code: "DAL", name: "Delta Airlines"}
2: {id: "526", code: "SWA", name: "Southwest Airlines"}
3: {id: "27", code: "ASA", name: "Alaska Airlines"}
4: {id: "23", code: "FDX", name: "FedEx"}
5: {id: "205", code: "NCA", name: "Nippon Cargo"}
6: {id: "406", code: "UPS", name: "United Parcel Service"}
7: {id: "160", code: "CPA", name: "Cathay Pacific"}
8: {id: "403", code: "PAC", name: "Polar Air Cargo"}
9: {id: "992", code: "GTI", name: "Atlas Air"}
10: {id: "272", code: "CKS", name: "Kalitta Air"}
11: {id: "345", code: "NAC", name: "Northern Air Cargo"}
12: {id: "615", code: "BCS", name: "European Air Transport"}
length: 13
__proto__: Array(0)

(12) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 6, code: "DAL", name: "Delta Airlines"}
1: {id: 526, code: "SWA", name: "Southwest Airlines"}
2: {id: 27, code: "ASA", name: "Alaska Airlines"}
3: {id: 23, code: "FDX", name: "FedEx"}
4: {id: 205, code: "NCA", name: "Nippon Cargo"}
5: {id: 406, code: "UPS", name: "United Parcel Service"}
6: {id: 160, code: "CPA", name: "Cathay Pacific"}
7: {id: 403, code: "PAC", name: "Polar Air Cargo"}
8: {id: 992, code: "GTI", name: "Atlas Air"}
9: {id: 272, code: "CKS", name: "Kalitta Air"}
10: {id: 345, code: "NAC", name: "Northern Air Cargo"}
11: {id: 615, code: "BCS", name: "European Air Transport"}
length: 12
__proto__: Array(0)
```

`console.log(updates);` results in:

```
[]length: 0__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: provide some data

Comment: @AbhishekMani I appended my OP

Comment: in this case there should be 12 matches

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `airlines` `id` property is a string, while `this.airlines` `id` property is a number. Change the comparison from `===` (strict) to `==` (abstract).

See [Equality comparisons and sameness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) on mdn.

```js
const airlines = [{"id":"1","code":"AAL","name":"American Airlines"},{"id":"6","code":"DAL","name":"Delta Airlines"},{"id":"526","code":"SWA","name":"Southwest Airlines"},{"id":"27","code":"ASA","name":"Alaska Airlines"},{"id":"23","code":"FDX","name":"FedEx"},{"id":"205","code":"NCA","name":"Nippon Cargo"},{"id":"406","code":"UPS","name":"United Parcel Service"},{"id":"160","code":"CPA","name":"Cathay Pacific"},{"id":"403","code":"PAC","name":"Polar Air Cargo"},{"id":"992","code":"GTI","name":"Atlas Air"},{"id":"272","code":"CKS","name":"Kalitta Air"},{"id":"345","code":"NAC","name":"Northern Air Cargo"},{"id":"615","code":"BCS","name":"European Air Transport"}];

const thisAirlines = [{"id":6,"code":"DAL","name":"Delta Airlines"},{"id":526,"code":"SWA","name":"Southwest Airlines"},{"id":27,"code":"ASA","name":"Alaska Airlines"},{"id":23,"code":"FDX","name":"FedEx"},{"id":205,"code":"NCA","name":"Nippon Cargo"},{"id":406,"code":"UPS","name":"United Parcel Service"},{"id":160,"code":"CPA","name":"Cathay Pacific"},{"id":403,"code":"PAC","name":"Polar Air Cargo"},{"id":992,"code":"GTI","name":"Atlas Air"},{"id":272,"code":"CKS","name":"Kalitta Air"},{"id":345,"code":"NAC","name":"Northern Air Cargo"},{"id":615,"code":"BCS","name":"European Air Transport"}];

const updates = airlines.filter(airline => 
  thisAirlines.some(item => item.id == airline.id)
);

console.log(updates);
```

Instead of using abstract equality you can convert the string `id` to a number using `+` - `+airlines.id` or convert the number to a string using - `String(this.airlines.id`).

```js
const airlines = [{"id":"1","code":"AAL","name":"American Airlines"},{"id":"6","code":"DAL","name":"Delta Airlines"},{"id":"526","code":"SWA","name":"Southwest Airlines"},{"id":"27","code":"ASA","name":"Alaska Airlines"},{"id":"23","code":"FDX","name":"FedEx"},{"id":"205","code":"NCA","name":"Nippon Cargo"},{"id":"406","code":"UPS","name":"United Parcel Service"},{"id":"160","code":"CPA","name":"Cathay Pacific"},{"id":"403","code":"PAC","name":"Polar Air Cargo"},{"id":"992","code":"GTI","name":"Atlas Air"},{"id":"272","code":"CKS","name":"Kalitta Air"},{"id":"345","code":"NAC","name":"Northern Air Cargo"},{"id":"615","code":"BCS","name":"European Air Transport"}];

const thisAirlines = [{"id":6,"code":"DAL","name":"Delta Airlines"},{"id":526,"code":"SWA","name":"Southwest Airlines"},{"id":27,"code":"ASA","name":"Alaska Airlines"},{"id":23,"code":"FDX","name":"FedEx"},{"id":205,"code":"NCA","name":"Nippon Cargo"},{"id":406,"code":"UPS","name":"United Parcel Service"},{"id":160,"code":"CPA","name":"Cathay Pacific"},{"id":403,"code":"PAC","name":"Polar Air Cargo"},{"id":992,"code":"GTI","name":"Atlas Air"},{"id":272,"code":"CKS","name":"Kalitta Air"},{"id":345,"code":"NAC","name":"Northern Air Cargo"},{"id":615,"code":"BCS","name":"European Air Transport"}];

const updates = airlines.filter(airline => 
  thisAirlines.some(item => item.id === +airline.id)
);

console.log(updates);
```

Since your using typescript, and you're doing this comparison several times, it's better to create a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of `this.airlines` string ids, band use that to compare:

```js
const airlines = [{"id":"1","code":"AAL","name":"American Airlines"},{"id":"6","code":"DAL","name":"Delta Airlines"},{"id":"526","code":"SWA","name":"Southwest Airlines"},{"id":"27","code":"ASA","name":"Alaska Airlines"},{"id":"23","code":"FDX","name":"FedEx"},{"id":"205","code":"NCA","name":"Nippon Cargo"},{"id":"406","code":"UPS","name":"United Parcel Service"},{"id":"160","code":"CPA","name":"Cathay Pacific"},{"id":"403","code":"PAC","name":"Polar Air Cargo"},{"id":"992","code":"GTI","name":"Atlas Air"},{"id":"272","code":"CKS","name":"Kalitta Air"},{"id":"345","code":"NAC","name":"Northern Air Cargo"},{"id":"615","code":"BCS","name":"European Air Transport"}];

const thisAirlines = [{"id":6,"code":"DAL","name":"Delta Airlines"},{"id":526,"code":"SWA","name":"Southwest Airlines"},{"id":27,"code":"ASA","name":"Alaska Airlines"},{"id":23,"code":"FDX","name":"FedEx"},{"id":205,"code":"NCA","name":"Nippon Cargo"},{"id":406,"code":"UPS","name":"United Parcel Service"},{"id":160,"code":"CPA","name":"Cathay Pacific"},{"id":403,"code":"PAC","name":"Polar Air Cargo"},{"id":992,"code":"GTI","name":"Atlas Air"},{"id":272,"code":"CKS","name":"Kalitta Air"},{"id":345,"code":"NAC","name":"Northern Air Cargo"},{"id":615,"code":"BCS","name":"European Air Transport"}];

const thisAirlinesSet = thisAirlines.reduce((s, o) => s.add(String(o.id)), new Set);

const updates = airlines.filter(airline => 
  thisAirlinesSet.has(airline.id)
);

console.log(updates);
```

Comment: You were faster!Props to you my friend.

Comment: Thanks, my eyes must be tired, I didn't catch that. Becuase I actually have to submit this to an API, I went ahead and mapped the array to new objects and used +airline.id,

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the filter method is using `===` operator which compares also the variable types if im correct.Both arrays have different id types, `this.airlines` have id of type `number` and the `airlines` have the id of type `string`.Replacing `===` operator to `==` should solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

You are using "===" to compare, so its must be the same type of comparison!
In this case, you can use "==" to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
 const updates = airlines.filter(airline => this.airlines.some(item => +item.id === +airline.id));
```

You are using `===` which means type is also checked, so add a `+` sign to parse it to `int` and safe checking.